# HappyBase - not showing results

Tags: python, hbase, happybase

Am trying to connect to hbase from python using HappyBase

Here is the code which am trying

```
>import happybase
>connection = happybase.Connection(host = <myHost>,port = <myPort>)
   <happybase.connection.Connection object at 0x7ff46c527bd0>
>connection.tables()
   ---> runs for real long time never ending <----
```

Same when I try to access a table

```
>import happybase
>connection = happybase.Connection(host = <someHost>,port = <somePort>, autoconnect=False)
>connection.open()
>table = connection.table('myTable')
   <happybase.table.Table name='myTable'>
>row = table.row('1234')
    -----> Nothing shows up - takes forever <-------
```

Can someone help me understand what's going wrong.

Btw, am using:

> java version "1.8.0_60"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build1.8.0_60-b27)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I had to start thrift server & connect to it inorder to connect to hbase.

Hope this helps others !!